# The work on a falling object and the Earth

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, newtonian-gravity, work, inertial-frames

Work is force by distance.

Take an object of mass $m$ held some distance $h$ above the surface of the Earth.

The mass of the Earth is $M$.

The force of attraction between the Earth and the object is $F$.

The force on the object due to the Earth is the same as the force on the Earth due to the object.

When the object is dropped it falls a distance $d$ while the Earth moves up a distance $D$

$d+D=h$

Up and down are of course arbitrary.

The work done on the object is $Fd$ while the work done on the Earth is $FD$.

But $Fd \ne FD$

Why are these not the same ?

Comment: Keep in mind that $F$ is not a constant force ([inverse square law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_law_of_universal_gravitation)) and the work done must be evaluated using integration in such cases.

Answer (score 2):

The work done by the gravitational force on $m$ is given by $(1)$ and the work done by the gravitational force on $M$ is given by $(2)$.
Assuming they were at rest initially ($v_m$ and $v_M$ are the final velocities attained by the two masses),
$$W_m=\int \mathbf{F}_m\cdot ds_m=\Delta KE_m=KE^{\text{final}}_m=\frac{1}{2}mv_m^2 \tag{1}$$
$$W_M=\int \mathbf{F}_M\cdot ds_M=\Delta KE_M =KE^{\text{final}}_M=\frac{1}{2}Mv_M^2\tag{2}$$
Conservation of momentum implies,
$$mv_m=Mv_M \tag{4}$$
$$W_m=KE^{\text{final}}_m=\frac{1}{2}mv^2_m=\frac{M}{m}\frac{1}{2}Mv_M^2=\frac{M}{m}KE^{\text{final}}_M =\frac{M}{m}W_M\tag{5}$$
Therefore, the work done on $m$ and $M$ are not the same.

> Why are these not the same?

Why do you think they should be the same?

Answer (score 0):

"Earth moves up by a distance D" - My question is earth moves up with respect to what? What is your frame of reference for the distance D and d?

Let's assume your frame of reference is Earth. In this case, $d = h$ and $D=0.$

Now, work done by force of gravity (derivation of following formula can be found in any textbook of physics),
$$W_g=GMm[\frac{1}{R}-\frac{1}{R+h}] \approx mgh$$where R = Radius of the earth, g = acceleration due to gravity near earth surface.

You may take any frame of reference, you will get the same $W_g$ and is always independent of the initial or final speed of the object.